# WSO2 API Manager: Generate multiple acces tokens for single user

Tags: wso2

A subscriber is using WSO2 API Manager to generate an access-token. This token is a single-sign-on ticket. Generating a new access-token, will make the previous access-token invalid. Is it possible to generate a new access-token, while the previous one will still be valid.

Comment: No, It is not possible to maintain multiple access tokens. What is your actual usecase? why do you need to maintain multiple access tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently API Manager supports two types of tokens. 
Application Access Tokens - This can be shared among several users, and no user credentials are needed to generate this.
User  Tokens - When generating a token of this type, user credentials are needed; therefore this is usually specific to a single user. You can have two active tokens by creating one from each type. But it won't be possible to have two active user tokens or two active Application Access Tokens.

Comment: If you use application-access-tokens and this token expires, who generates a new one if you have shared the token to multiple users.

Comment: Application Access Token is generated using the client credential grant type. So you can call the token endpoint like this to generate an application token.
curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=PRODUCTION" -H "Authorization: Basic Base64Encoded(Consumer key:consumer secret), Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" localhost:8243/token
This will generate a new access token if it's expired, or else it'll return the current active token.